# Solve the equation $x^4-2x^3-21x^2+22x+40=0$ whose roots are in A.P.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, arithmetic-progressions

Solve the equation $x^4-2x^3-21x^2+22x+40=0$ whose roots are in A.P. (arithmetic progression).

I don't understand this solution.

[image: I don't understand this solution.]

**Why are the terms of AP considered as mentioned in the question and not in the form of a, a+d, a+2d... and so on?**

I am not able to understand why the terms of the AP are of that specific form and not in the general form of a, a+d, a+2d and a+3d. The aforementioned sequence is also in the form of AP and should also provide the answer but I am not able to get to the answer by the approach I am trying.

**Also explain the approach as well.**

Also the reasoning and thinking behind the approach used to find the roots if explained will also be helpful or any sources for the same.

**Approach**

Consider the 4 roots to be {a, a+d, a+2d and a+3d}. By using Vieta's formula:\

$a+(a+d)+(a+2d)+(a+3d)= \frac{-b}{a}$
$4a+6d=2$
$2a+3d=1$
$a= \frac{(1-3d)}{2}$

Similarly,
$a*(a+d)*(a+2d)*(a+3d)= \frac{c}{a}$
$(a^2+ad)*(a^2+3ad+2ad+6d^2)=40$

Then substituting the value of $a$ in the above equation:
$221d^4-90d^3-66d^2+6d-639=0$

There may be some errors but it will result in a quartic equation nonetheless and it goes back again being similar to the original equation. Thus my question is then is there no other way of solving this equation other than considering the terms of the Arithmetic Progression to be of a particular sequence.

**I am new to math.stack exchange** so if there are any error in the phrasing of the question, I am sorry. Also any help is welcomed kindly.
Thanks and regards. Special thanks to everyone who pointed out the mistakes in paraphrasing of my initial question and guiding me.

Comment: Please don't rely on images (type instead), and edit your post to include 1) your own attempt(s) ("the approach I am trying") 2) What precise step(s) you don't understand in the solution you were given.

Comment: Also saying what AP is will help… Rather than letting the reader to guess.

Comment: The four roots being $b,b+r,b+2r$ and $b+3r$, if you set $d=r/2$ and $a=b+3d$ they can be rewritten $a-3d,a-d,a+d,a+3d.$ The advantage is to have simpler calculations, but if yours (which you should really show) were done with $b,r$, it works as well.

Comment: The author of the answer is exploiting symmetry to make the algebra easier. It would work your way if you persist.

Comment: Dhuri, if you do not want moderators to close your question, you should add your attempts of solution to your post.

Comment: Knowing that the roots form an arithmetic progression isn't *necessary* for solving the equation.  You can just use the Rational Root Theorem to conclude that any rational roots must be factors of 40, and then obtain $x \in \{-4, -1, 2, 5\}$ by trying all the possible factors.

Comment: "*Then substituting the value of $a$ in the above equation...*" $\;-\;$ Recheck your calculations there. Once you fix the mistakes you get a much simpler equation.

Comment: @dxiv I am trying /unable to figure out my mistake. If you are implying about the addition of 2ad and 3ad I am aware of it. However it will still result in a quartic equation later. If you are relating to some other mistake please guide me so. Thanks and regards

Comment: @B10DhuriJayantGangadhar You should be getting $\,9 d^4 - 10 d^2 - 639 = 0\,$ instead. No one can guess where your mistake is if you don't post the steps.

Comment: Well, if you don't want to exploit the symmetry as the textbook answer does, and you don't want a quartic to solve, you still can use the Vieta relation involving the coefficient of $x^2$.  That will lead to a quadratic to solve after substitution, presumably easier than the quartic.

Comment: @dxiv I am sorry I was trying to rectify my mistakes. There were a bunch of mistakes with not expanding each term properly and sign errors as well. I did reach your conclusion but there are still some mistakes I guess because the equations are not the same as provided as answer in the book

Comment: @B10DhuriJayantGangadhar The equations will not be the same, because your $a,d$ are different from the $a,d$ in the answer book. But if you carry out the remaining steps you'll get the correct end results.

Comment: @dxiv Hey I reached the solution to the problem. I am really grateful for your help. I created my account a few hours ago and am overwhelmed how welcoming this community is. Once again thanks for taking time to help me and sorry for any mistakes which happened from my part. Hope you continue to help in the future because I believe I am going to need a lot of it and also hope to help someone just like you helped me in the future. Once again thanks and regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally when considering AP's with 3,4,5 terms respectively, it makes it easier if we write the terms as:  (which makes calculating terms of the AP much faster(especially sum and product)  )

- $3: a-r,a,a+r$
- $4: a-3r,a-r,a+r,a+3r$
- $5: a-2r,a-r,a,a+r,a+2r$

You can then exploit using Vietta's Relations of Sum and Product of roots to get values of a and r respectively, as outline in the solution provided by them.

Using $a,a+r,a+2r,a+3r$ will make the calculations much more tedious as you will get a linear relation between a and r and a 4th power one which will not easily cancel.

Answer (score 0):

Let the equation have a rational root $x=\frac{m}{n}$, then
$$\frac{m^4}{n^4}-\frac{2m^3}{n^3}-\frac{21m^2}{n^2}+\frac{22m}{n}+40=0, \; m\in\mathbb{Z}, \; n\in \mathbb{N}$$
$$40n^4+22mn^3-21m^2n^2-2m^3n+m^4=0$$
$$m^4=n\left ( 40n^3+22mn^2-21m^2n-2m^3 \right )$$

A natural number has no common prime divisors, then $n$ is a divisor of $1$, so $n$ equals one
$$40n^4=22mn^3-21m^2n^2-2m^3n+m^4$$
$$40n^4=m\left ( 22n^3-21mn^3-2m^2n+m^3 \right )$$

A natural number has no prime divisors, then $m$ is a divisor of $40$, hence, $m$ is equal to one of the numbers $\pm 5$, $\pm 2$, $\pm 1$. Note that $1$ cannot be a root of the equation since the sum of the coefficients of our equation is not zero, but $-1$ is a root of the equation since
$1+2-21-22+40=0\Rightarrow x_1=-1$

Our equation then takes the form
$$(x+1)\left ( x^3 - 3 x^2 - 18 x + 40 \right )=0$$

Do the same with the cubic equation and find that $x_2=2$, hence
$$(x+1)(x-2)\left ( x^2-x-20 \right )=0$$

This is already a simple quadratic equation, hence $x_{3,4}=\left \{ -4.5 \right \}$

Comment: You should write that $m$ is equal to one of the numbers $\color{red}{\pm40},\color{red}{\pm20},\color{red}{\pm10},\color{red}{\pm8},\pm5,\color{red}{\pm4},\pm2,\pm1$, instead of $\pm5,\pm2,\pm1$. Indeed, also $\color{red}{\pm40},\color{red}{\pm20},\color{red}{\pm10},\color{red}{\pm8},\color{red}{\pm4}$ are divisors of $40$.

Answer (score 0):

The declaration that the zeroes of a polynomial are in arithmetic progression automatically implies that the zeroes (which have multiplicity 1) are arranged symmetrically about their average. As you found, their sum is $ \ 4a + 6d \ = \ 2 \ \ , \ $ making their average $ \ a + \frac32·d \ = \ \frac12 \ \ . \ $  So if we consider these numbers relative to the average, we have $ \ -\frac32·d \ \ , \ \ -\frac12·d \ \ , \ \  +\frac12·d \ \ , \ \ +\frac32·d \ \ $ "centered" on $ \ \frac12 \ \ . \ $  (The provided solution could well have explained this a bit more thoroughly.)

The product of the zeroes is then $$ \ \left(\frac12 - \frac32·d \right)·\left(\frac12 - \frac12·d \right)·\left(\frac12 + \frac12·d \right)·\left(\frac12 + \frac32·d \right) $$ $$ = \ \ \left(\frac14 - \frac14·d^2 \right)·\left(\frac14 - \frac94·d^2 \right) \ \ = \ \ 40 \ \ , $$
leading to the biquadratic equation shown in the solution. (The version shown here has real solutions $ \ d \ = \ \pm 3 \ \ , \ $ which will lead to the same result.  The remark in the solution that $ \ d \ = \ -3 \ $ is "inadmissible" is not really correct, since a negative difference simply means we have a "descending" arithmetic progression, with initial term $ \ a' \ = \ \frac{2 \ - \ 6·[-3]}{4} \  \ = \ 5 \ \     $ and the same set of zeroes for our polynomial.)  So the use of $ \ a - 3d \ , \ a - d \ , \ a + d \ , \ a + 3d \ \ $ is not simply a "choice of convenience", but arises directly from the inherent symmetry of the arithmetic progression.

We can alternatively apply the "shift" to the quartic polynomial $ \ f(x) \ = \ x^4 - 2x^3 - 21x^2 + 22x + 40 \ $ by taking $ \ x \ = \ u + \frac12 \ \   $ thus
$$ f \left(u + \frac12 \right) \ \ = \ \ \left(u + \frac12 \right)^4 \ - \ 2\left(u + \frac12 \right)^3 \ - \ 21\left(u + \frac12 \right)^2 \ + \ 22\left(u + \frac12 \right) \ + \ 40 \ $$
to produce the "depressed" polynomial
$$ u^4 \ - \ \frac{45}{2}·u^2 \ + \ \frac{729}{16} \ \ = \ \ \left(u^2 - \frac{45}{4} - 9 \right)·\left(u^2 - \frac{45}{4} + 9 \right)  \ \  = \ \ \left(u^2 - \frac{81}{4}   \right)·\left(u^2 - \frac{9}{4}  \right) \ \ . $$
The zeroes are then
$$ u \ \ = \ \ x \ - \ \frac12 \ \ = \ \ -\frac92 \ \  ,  \ \ -\frac32 \ \  ,  \ \ +\frac32 \ \  ,  \ \ +\frac92 \ \ \Rightarrow   \ \   x  \ \ = \ \ -4 \ \  ,  \ \ -1 \ \  ,  \ \ +2 \ \  ,  \ \ +5 \ \ . $$

$$ \ \ $$

**ADDENDUM (5/30) --** We can generalize this discussion to say that if the zeroes of a polynomial are in arithmetic progression and

• the polynomial is of even degree $ \ 2n \ \   ( \ c_{2n}x^{2n} + c_{2n \ - \ 1}x^{2n \ - \ 1} + \ \ldots \ + c_1x + c_0 \ ) \ \ , \ $ then the average of its zeroes is $ \ a \ = \ \large{-\frac{c_{2n \ - \ 1}}{2n \ · \ c_{2n} } } \ \  $ and the difference $ \ d \ $ between zeroes in the sequence is found from
$$ \left(a^2 - \frac14·d^2 \right)·\left(a^2 - \frac94·d^2 \right)· \ \ldots \ · \left(a^2 - \frac{(2n \ - \ 1)^2}{4}·d^2 \right) \ \ = \ \ \frac{c_0}{c_{2n}} \ \ . \ $$
Alternatively, the polynomial may be transformed as $ \ f(x) \ \rightarrow \ f(u + a) \ \ , \ $ which then has even symmetry with  zeroes being $ \ u \ = \ \pm \frac12·d \ \ , \ \ \pm \frac32·d \ \ , \ \ldots \ , \ \ \pm \frac{(2n \ - \ 1) }{2}·d \ \ ; \ \  $ or

• the polynomial is of odd degree $ \ 2n + 1 \ \   ( \ c_{2n \ + \ 1}x^{2n \ + \ 1} + c_{2n }x^{2n } + \ \ldots \ + c_1x + c_0 \ ) \ \ , \ $ then the average of its zeroes is $ \ a \ = \ \large{-\frac{c_{2n }}{(2n \ + \ 1) \ · \ c_{2n \ + \ 1} } } \ \  $ *is* one of the zeroes, and the difference $ \ d \ $ between zeroes in the sequence is found from
$$ \left(a^2 - d^2 \right)·\left(a^2 - 4d^2 \right)· \ \ldots \ · \left(a^2 - n^2d^2 \right) \ \ = \ \ \frac{-c_0}{a \ · \ c_{2n \ + \ 1}} \ \ . \ $$
We may also transform the polynomial  as $ \ f(x) \ \rightarrow \ f(u + a) \ \ , \ $ which has odd symmetry with the  zeroes being $ \ u \ = \ 0 \ \ , \ \ \pm d \ \ , \ \ \pm 2·d \ \ , \ \ldots \ , \ \ \pm n·d \ \ . $

As an illustration of the odd-degree case, we are given that the zeroes for $ \ 27x^5 + 45x^4 - 210x^3 - 230x^2 + 263x + 105 \ $ are in arithmetic progression.  One of the zeroes is the average of the zeroes, $ \ a \ = \ -\frac{45}{5 \ · \ 27} \ = \ -\frac13 \ \ . \ $  We may find the difference between the zeroes in the progression from
$$ \left( \ \left[-\frac13 \right]^2 - d^2 \ \right)·\left( \ \left[-\frac13 \right]^2 - 4d^2 \ \right) \ \ = \ \ \frac{-105}{(-1/3)·27}  $$
$$ \rightarrow \ \ 4·d^4 \  - \ \frac59·d^2 \ - \ \frac{944}{81} \ \ = \ \ 4·\left( \ d^2  \ - \ \frac{5 \ + \ 123}{72} \ \right)·\left( \ d^2  \ - \ \frac{5 \ - \ 123}{72} \ \right)  $$
$$ = \ \ 4·\left( \ d^2  \ - \ \frac{16}{9} \ \right)·\left( \ d^2  \ + \ \frac{59}{36} \ \right) \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ ,  $$
for which the real roots are $ \ d \ = \ \pm \frac43 \ \ . \ $  If we instead work with the transformed polynomial, we obtain
$$ f \left(u + \frac13 \right) \ \ = \ \ 27u^5 \ - \ 240u^3 \ + \ \frac{1024}{3}·u \ \ = \ \ \frac{u}{3}·(9u^2 \ - \ 64)·(9u^2 \ - \ 16) \ \ . $$
Either method yields the arithmetic sequence of zeroes
$$ -\frac13 - 2·\frac43 \ = \ -3 \ \ , \ \ -\frac13 - \frac43 \ = \ -\frac53 \ \ , \ \ -\frac13 \ \ , $$ $$ -\frac13 + \frac43 \ = \ +1 \ \ , \ \ -\frac13 + 2·\frac43 \ = \ +\frac73 \ \ . $$